# @font-face not working properly issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/xLj47/) reproduces the problem.

I have a custom font and I used `@font-face` to import it. Originally I wanted to use it in `<canvas>` but it is not working.

```
ctx.font = "16px test";
```

Then I figure out it isn't working as well outside `<canvas>`.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: test;
    src: url('http://example.com/iLiHei.ttf');
}
#custom{
    font-family: "test", monospace;
}
```

Is the font file itself the problem? Because I can't see any error in the CSS.

[image]

> The top row and the bottom row should be using different fonts but they are not.

I don't care about different browsers since I am using it in a Chrome extension. Any idea why isn't this working?

Comment: No error in browser console, but in Firefox's traditional "error console", I can see that Firefox refuse to parse this file because there's some issue in one of the "table": `Error: downloadable font: table 'GDEF': failed to parse table...`

Answer (score 0):

Drawing to the canvas happens immediately but the browser has to load the font from the server. So when you draw to the canvas, the font isn't ready and therefore defaults to a default one.

You could create an element on the page that forces the font to load.

```
<div style="font-family:test;display:none"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not drawing the text automatically when it loads, and also because the file is in the extension itself it loads immediately. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to replicate the problem and indeed it doesn't show something else than monospace. But no wonder, that font file should be around 21mb! At some point it sometimes just either closes connection and leaves an only partially downloaded file or needs a lot of time until it is able to render it.

Do you really want to make the pageload dependant on a font file that big?
Best advise would be to find a better font file, smaller in size.

Comment: I'm actually using it in a chrome extension so the size doesn't really matter. Everything "downloads" instantly; also I have another even larger font, but the weird thing is that font it *does* work.